# Z-Index of Elements within Zend PDF

Tags: pdf, zend-framework

Im using Zend PDF to try and create a PDF document.

I want to draw a rectangle underneath some text however the rectangle just seems to show on top and cannot find any information about positioning on the z axis within documentation.

```
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.8))
          ->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.2))
          ->setLineDashingPattern(array(3, 2, 3, 4), 1.6)
          ->drawRectangle(280, 660, 400, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to the z index possibly just create elements later.

My issue was as below:

```
->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.8))
```

Above was setting the colour of the text to the same as the  rectangle therefore making it seem like it was below / invisible. Resetting the fill color later for my text seems to sort out my problem here.